# Page titles with router event returns same title in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular7

I have following routes and changing titles using router events from `AppComponent` like below.
AppRoutingModule

```
  { path: 'Home', component: ErrorComponent, data: {  title: 'Home Page' } },
  { path: 'Login', component: LoginComponent, data: {  title: 'Login' } },
  { path: 'ForgotPassword', component: ForgotComponent, data: {  title: 'Forgot Password' } },

  { path: 'Register', component: RegisterComponent, data: {  title: 'New Registration' } },
  { path: 'Register/:id', component: RegisterComponent, data: {  title: 'Update Profile' } }
```

Here, if I navigate to in between Home, Login, ForgotPassword everything works as expected but when navigate to Register once, then navigate to any other page it gives me Register Page's title for all further navigation(s).

AppComponent

```
constructor(private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private titleService: Title) {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map(() => this.activatedRoute),
      map((route: any) => {
        while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
        return route;
      }),
      filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary'),
      mergeMap((route: any) => route.data)).subscribe((event) => {
        this.titleService.setTitle(event['title']);
        console.log('Page Title', event['title']);
      });
  }
```

What am I missing here? I am using Angular 7.

Comment: Colud you create a https://stackblitz.com fiddle, please?

Comment: Does the console also log "Register Page's title" or does it log the correct title?

Comment: I created a fiddle for me it works, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-title-by-routing

Comment: I too just created a fiddle and working fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4basu6 but unfortunately not working in my real project. I think some thing else I am missing.

Comment: Do you get some console error within your real project? If there is a error in your listener the listener could be disconnected and so your title-pipe wont execute anymore resulting in an unchanged title.

Comment: No such errors. https://ibb.co/TWkfVp0

Comment: Could you try to use ``this.router.routerState.root`` instead of `this.activatedRoute`, does it help`?

Comment: this.router.routerState.root is working. Any explanation for this?

Comment: Im no anuglar pro, but I would say ActivatedRoute is a service and it would be injected once in AppComponent with the current routed route instance. So after routing the service is not injected again and so you still have the old route. But why it does work until you route "Register" oO mmh.
Using route (also a service but always the same instance) and getting the current activatedRoute on deman will you always give the current / active one. So my explanation, though not complete

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you can use following approach to have dynamic titles on every route change

this is working fine for me

first create new `.ts file` named as

> page-titles.ts

in `constants` folder of `root folder`(or anywhere you want)

```
export const DETAILS = {
    HOME_PAGE: {
        title: 'Millions of reviews analyzed & ranked',
        meta: 'cc analyzes all reviews from all review sites and shows you what other consumers find important.',
    },
    SEARCH_REVIEW: {
        title: 'Search Results -test.com',
        meta: '',
    },
    TERMS: {
        title: 'Terms and Conditions',
        meta: '',
    },
    BLOGS: {
        title: 'The Consumerchoice Blog',
        meta: '',
    },
    BLOG_DETAILS: {
        title: 'Blog post title',
        meta: '',
    },
    PRESSES: {
        title: 'Consumerchoice in the Press',
        meta: '',
    },
    PRESS_DETAILS: {
        title: 'Press post title test',
        meta: '',
    },
    ABOUT: {
        title: 'Learn about Consumerchoice and our team',
        meta: '',
    },
    CONTACT: {
        title: 'Contact test.com',
        meta: '',
    },
    FAQS: {
        title: 'Questions and Answers',
        meta: '',
    },
    CATEGORY: {
        title: 'All test.com Categories',
        meta: '',
    },
    SERVICE_DETAILS: {
        title: 'Home | Service Details',
        meta: '',
    }
}
```

this file will have key pair values in main constant object here i.e. `DETAILS` where each key of `DETAILS` object represents page name(component name associated to specific route)so, you no need to set data property in route

then inside your specific route's component simply use `seTitle` method to set title

here for example i want to set title for `Terms Page` then add this code inside constructor of that component

> terms.component.ts

```
import { DETAILS } from '../../constants/page-details';


constructor(public titleService: Title,) {

   this.titleService.setTitle(DETAILS.TERMS.title);

}
```

let me know if this helps you!!

**OR** just try to update your constructor of `app.component.ts` with following code

```
constructor(
    public router: Router,
    public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    public titleService: Title
  ) {
    router.events
      .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .subscribe((event) => {
        console.log('title from route data :', 
         activatedRoute.root.firstChild.snapshot.data['title']);
        this.title = 
         activatedRoute.root.firstChild.snapshot.data['title'];
        this.titleService.setTitle(this.title);
      })
     }
```

Comment: Ya, this is one way to setTitle but the thing here is that we need to update every component's ts file where as using router event, only adding one snippet AppComponent is enough. Will wait for some time, if no answer comes, i will use this option. Thank you.

Comment: yes, you are right in that way if want to have less code

Comment: i have edited my answer and suggested you  what can work here, try that!!